# Etymology of a strange sense of "kick", as in, "I'm on a Sailor Moon kick right now"

Tags: etymology, meaning

[I'm not *really* on a Sailor Moon kick. ^_^]  Still, the use of the word *kick* to denote the feeling of a "current or temporary pleasure" is pretty strange, isn't it?  How did it evolve from its original root, which I presume is the sense of striking something with the foot, to that meaning?  My question is: Can anyone draw **a plausible pathway** from the most original meaning to this colloquial meaning of *kick*?

**EDIT**: Er, my example sentence didn't say, *I get a kick out of Sailor Moon.*  It said, *I'm on a Sailor Moon kick*.  I think these senses are very distinguishable, and thus the answers I've received thus far strike me as wrong.

Comment: If you think very hard, you can catch a glimpse of this as being a metaphor.

Comment: Well there is [this manga](http://wikimoon.org/index.php?title=Sailor_Moon_Kick) returned by google.

Comment: To address your edit: I think it's a fairly straightforward transformation from "I get a kick out of X" to "I am on an X kick". Similar to "I get high on X" to "I am on an X high", or "I am hiking up the Nile" to "I am on a Nile hike".

Comment: You wrote "current or temporary pleasure", rather than a current or temporary period of sustained activity or interest, which I think is what you mean. To me that's the main confusing thing about this question.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff Hm, I see where the confusion might have come from.  I was using this perhaps dated definition of _pleasure_, cribbed from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pleasure): _"A source of enjoyment or delight"_...that's why I used the article 'a', because this _pleasure_ is countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a reasonable progression from *"getting a kick out of something"* to *"being on a Sailor Moon kick."* This is through references to alcohol or drugs; here being on a kick could mean an extended period of using alcohol or drugs.

From James Jones' *Here to Eternity* (1951):

> He had seen members of the Canned Heat
>   Brigade stay on a kick like this for
>   years. ... And they didnt even have
>   whiskey; all they had had was canned
>   heat from Woolworth's that they had to
>   strain the alcohol out of the paraffin
>   through a handkerchief and then strain
>   the alky through a piece of stale
>   bread.

This reference is right around the time when *"being on an xxxxx kick"* starts showing up in Google books searches.

Comment: +1, in my dialect it definitely means an extended period of heightened interest/use/etc.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kick

> Meaning "surge or fit of pleasure"
>   (often as kicks) is from 1941;
>   originally lit., "stimulation from
>   liquor or drugs" (1844).

that aside, I would expect you to be on "A Sailor moon *high*" and not on a kick

Comment: I don't understand the *high* remark. "A Sailor Moon kick" seems more likely to me.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q="on+a+Sailor+Moon+high"

Comment: That doesn't clarify it to me, I'm afraid... that search gives only 6 results, not counting this page; google.com/search?q="on+a+Sailor+Moon+kick" gives only 28 (probably not a statistically significant difference).

Comment: Being on an xxx high sounds to me much more idiomatically correct than being on an xxx kick. I get a kick out of something that give me a high. When I get high on xxx I am on an xxx high.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q="stay+on+a+high"+-protein+-growth+-floor

Comment: @mplungjan Hmm. The sense of the word *kick* Billare's talking about is not interchangeable with *high*. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1260925?rskey=VadH8T&result=1#m_en_us1260925) say "[with modifier] a specified temporary interest or enthusiasm: *the jogging kick*"; Wiktionary offers this example: *I think I sprained something on my latest exercise kick.* [COCA](http://www.americancorpus.org/) offers: *For years I was on a self-improvement kick.*

Comment: Ok, let's just say I have never heard of being on an xxx kick and I have heard being on an xxx high often. I also have a feeling that since this question is Japanese Manga related, the users may not be native English speakers, but then neither am I.

Answer (score 1):

When someone says he or she gets a 'kick' from doing something, it is due to the extreme pleasure they get from the act, and as a result their body releases a bit of adrenaline into their system and they experience a *kick* from the extra energy.