# Idiom request: interested in doing something during a certain period of time

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I came across this idiom in a Youtube English idiom course. It goes like

> I'm on a sports [the single word I can't recall].

Basically, it means that I'm just not a sports person, however, I've started showing some interest recently or I was attracted to sports during a past (often short) period of time.

Comment: I'm on a sports _kick_: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24971/etymology-of-a-strange-sense-of-kick-as-in-im-on-a-sailor-moon-kick-right

Comment: @Gnawme You've nailed it. Feel free to add it as an answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase is:

> I'm on a sports ***kick***.

The Oxford Living Dictionary defines this sense of *[kick](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kick)* as

> *[with modifier]* A temporary interest in a particular thing.